# Qt4 QSettings read array with multiple values

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, ini, qsettings

I have an .ini file of this form:

```
#init file:

[files]
fileAmount=2

file1=string1, string2, 0
file2=string1, string2, 1



//cpp file:
settings=new QSettings(QString(":resources/configuration"), QSettings::IniFormat);

int n=set("files/fileAmount").toInt();

for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    QStringList list=settings->value("files/file"+QString::number(i)).toStringList();
    out<<list[0]<<" "<<list[1]<<" "<<list[2]<<endl;
}




//output:
string1 string2 0
string1 string2 1
```

Is there any way to set whitespaces as delimiter for QStringList instead of komma?
i.e have this file:

```
#init file:

[files]
fileAmount=2

file1=string1 string2 0
file2=string1 string2 1
```

and get the same output?

Comment: Please, show some code, what you already had tried.

Comment: and what if **string1** or **string2** have **whitespaces** inside ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ini File:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MyOrg\MyApp.ini

```
[files]
file1=string1 string2 0
```

Sample code for space delimited stringlist in ini file:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QDebug>

void readSettings();
void writeSettings();

QStringList list;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSettings::setDefaultFormat(QSettings::IniFormat);
    qApp->setApplicationName("MyApp");
    qApp->setOrganizationName("MyOrg");

    readSettings();

    qDebug() << list;

    writeSettings();

    return a.exec();
}

void readSettings()
{
    // read a space delimited value from QSettings string
    // into a stringlist
    QSettings s;

    s.beginGroup("files");

    QString temp = s.value("file1","string1 string2 0").toString();
    list << temp.split(" ");

    s.endGroup();
}

void writeSettings()
{
    // write a space delimited value from QStringList
    QSettings s;

    s.beginGroup("files");

    s.setValue("file1",list.join(" "));

    s.endGroup();
}
```

Output:

```
("string1", "string2", "0")
```

Hope that helps.